# WebScraping for names - NoneType error on find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract names (notifier) using BeautifulSoup. But when I test run it it gives a NoneType error: 
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page_counter = 1


while page_counter < 5:
    print('page number: %d' %page_counter)
    url = requests.get('http://zone-h.org/archive/page=%d'%page_counter,timeout=8).text()

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in these two lines:

```
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

`soup.find('table')` will return `None` if it cant find any element with the tag `table`. That would cause `table.find_all('tr')` to return the error you got, because `table` was assigned to `None` in the previous line.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and yes it absolutely makes sense. I ended up using selenium to extract the names. If there is a workaround on BeautifulSoup that I don't know about please let me know or let everyone know.

Comment: I'm not sure about a "workaround". Your BeautifulSoup code should work fine as long as a page with a `<table>` tag exists. That also requires that `soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')` loaded correctly. You might want verify that as well! I'm guessing when you made a selenium parser you adjusted your code in some way that alleviated these other issues.